# Reload DatePicker in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, datepicker

I have a button which shows the DatePicker. When app will start it shows the current Date.

But when i choose another date & hide the picker view & again try to see my datepicker it doesn't shows the current date.

**How can i solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So whenever you are showing the datepicker, set the current date to the datepicker.

```
datepicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected date for the date picker by using the following simple code:

```
[DatePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
```

or:

```
DatePicker.date = [NSDate date];
```

you can use any value for the selected date, and accordingly the date picker show that date when it opened

also you can use:

```
[DatePicker setDate:[NSDate date] animated:YES];
```

to add the animation for the selected row when the picker is opened